# onClick event not working - JS

Tags: javascript, php

I am writing a very simple search function that will return similar results from the database based on what the user selected, though when testing the onClick function it is not working I have checked my code with those similar and it should work, I searched before asking this question though no solution for me, this is a sample of the code..`

```
<form>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Search Form..</legend>
    <input type="text" id="itemID" name="itemName" placeholder="Enter item name.." />
    <select id="locSelect">
    <option id="loc1" value="mountain"> mountain </option>
    </select>
    </br>
    <input type="button" id="searchID" name="searchName" value="Search" onClick="runsearch();" />


</fieldset>
</form>

<div id="searchResult"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function runsearch()
{
    var item = $("#itemID").val();

    var location = document.getElementById("#locSelect");
    var selectedLoc = location.options[location.selectedIndex].text;

    if(item == '') 
    {
       alert("Item field is blank please specify an item");
    }

    else { $.post("LSR.php", {
        postitem = item,
        postlocation = selectedLoc },

        function(data)
        {
            $("#searchResult").html(data);
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

It should take what the user selected and send it to php page where it will compare with the database, I wrote similar code for a login/registration page and it worked, i'm not sure why this one doesn't, the only thing different is the select, options.. I would like to understand what I am doing wrong.
Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Try to declare your `runsearch` function before input tag where you use it

Comment: tried this, didn't work, search button still no output.

Comment: Select is only allowed to contain options and option groups. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select
I'm still looking at the rest but from experience that can cause all kinds of weird issues. Select elements are special and have some weird nuances.

Comment: I have tried this before, switching the button out and in select or in it's own form,  does not do anything but make it look weird, input is outside the closing select tag. I am reading up on the link now, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a catch 22 here, if you put the function above the form, `#itemID` doesn't exist in the DOM yet.  If you put the function below the form, the function `runsearch` doesn't exist yet.

Why not use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click", "#searchID", function(e){
        console.log("clicked!"); //watch console for this, delete this line once you know it works.
        runsearch();
    });
});
```

Also, you have a few things wrong with your code (including the colons/equal signs mentioned in another answer).  I've cleaned it up a bit.

This is wrong:
`document.getElementById("#locSelect");`

If you're using `document.getElementById`, you don't need the #.  That's a jQuery id selector.  But, you're using jQuery, so embrace it!  The equivalent of document.getElementById in jQuery is simply `$("#IDOFELEMENT")`.

All of this `location.options[location.selectedIndex].text` can be shortened to just this: `location.val()`, but I always use a $ to prefix jQuery objects so it's immediately obvious they're jQuery objects, so I renamed your variable to $location.

Here's a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/SeanKendle/b9udzjLp/

Comment: Thank you! it has worked now, the placement of the function didn't matter, the # was the problem deleting it or using your code worked.
A question location.val() will give the text within the options or it's value?

Comment: If you used my code, the placement of the function no longer matters because `$(document).ready()` waits for the entire DOM to load.  However, in raw Javascript placement is *everything*.  That is why people use things like jQuery, or even put their code into `window.onload = function()`.   But, again, you're using jQuery, so go all in!  Most things you do in jQuery must be in the `$(document).ready()` function.  Leave the other functions you write outside of it, however.

Comment: Did you look at my fiddle?

Comment: Yes, but my code is working without the $(document).ready() part, with it it reverts to no output, same if I change to location.val() instead of location.options[location.selectedIndex].text

Comment: Do you use Firebug?  If not, you should start.  The Console will tell you a lot of things, especially errors.  You can also `console.log()` whole objects and see all their parts!

Comment: Try copying my fiddle code exactly from the fiddle into your page and let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes worked, though i'm not quite sure how the $document.ready() works entirely, I take it console.log does not show anything without firebug? I'm using chrome atm

Comment: `$(document).ready` waits for the entire document object model to finish loading before doing anything.  It's extremely helpful.  Any time  you're adding event listeners, put the code in there.  You can open Chrome's console just like Firebug, hit F12, then click the "Console" tab!

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error in your function. Use this:

```
else { $.post("LSR.php", {
    postitem: item,
    postlocation: selectedLoc },
```

Instead of this:

```
else { $.post("LSR.php", {
    postitem = item,
    postlocation = selectedLoc },
```

You have another error:

```
var location = document.getElementById("#locSelect");
```

Should be:

```
var location = document.getElementById("locSelect");
```

And put the function before the button with onClick.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't noticed that, but search still gives no output, alert not functioning

Comment: @CarlosSakr Did you load jquery library?

Comment: Yes, double checked for any errors, none, working on all pages.

Comment: @CarlosSakr I found another error. Look at the update

Comment: Removing # worked, thank you, the placement of the function didn't matter

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the `<fieldset>` tag before you close the `<form>` tag, they are out of order.